Efficiently parse multi-level table from a PDF document using Python libraries
Table to be parsed
Can someone advise on how to efficiently extract this table (link above) from a PDF? I am primarily working with tabula as it seems to be the best Python library for identifying and extracting tables.
I would like to extract into a dataframe with the cell structure as per the image below:
csv
I am open to in-filling the nans with the sub-headers above/below.
The document ('doc') is the 2023 Annual Report of Marshalls plc (page number in actual document = 92), available at this link:
https://www.marshalls.co.uk/investor/results-reports-and-presentations
I have come up with the following code to extract the elements of each row, but it conflates some elements, e.g. the 5th element in row 1 (zero-based) should actually be two elements ('MIP A' and 'MIP B') rather than one ('MIP A MIP B'). As you can see, there should be 19 elements in each row including the name of the executive in the first column. Right now there are only 10 elements in each from the output of the code.
import tabula

dfs = tabula.read_pdf(doc, pages='94')     # multiple_tables=True
dfs

row_number = 1   # Row number you want to access (zero-based)

# Iterate over each DataFrame in the list and access a specified row of actual data
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    if not df.empty:  # Ensure DataFrame is not empty
        if len(df) > row_number:  # Check if DataFrame has enough rows
            specified_row = df.iloc[row_number]  # Access the specified row of data
            print(f"Data from row {row_number + 1} in Table {i+1}:")
            print(specified_row.values)  # Print only the values from the specified row
            print(f"\nNumber of elements in row {row_number + 1} of Table {i+1}: {len(specified_row.values)}")
        else:
            print(f"Table {i+1} does not contain row {row_number + 1}.")
    else:
        print(f"Table {i+1} is empty.")

I should add that I need to be able to apply to other tables and similarly detect delineation between cells so it's no good having specific references like the following:
def split_specific_items(row_values):
    updated_values = []
    for item in row_values:
        if item == 'MIP A MIP B':
            updated_values.extend(['MIP A', 'MIP B'])
        else:
            updated_values.append(item)
    return updated_values


Please read this page and edit your question accordingly ; Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Sorry - is that better?

Tabula and any other extractor will not be able to handle overlapping table headers even if they discard a line or two.

The best you can do is try several way and pick the best outcome, then edit as a table in MS Word.

Once the data looks correctly like a table. Simply copy and paste (see lower part of page) as an embedded spreadsheet. Then open in excel as a cellular layout and export as CSV.

Alternately export the data frame as CSV and add the headers in Excel.

Without headers
,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022,2023,2022
,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000,£'000
Martyn Coffey,676,621,43,44,34,93,127,70,"--",94,366,88,"1,246","1,010",753,758,493,252
Justin Lockwood,442,414,12,11,22,21,83,47,55,63,187,"--",801,556,476,446,325,110
Simon Bourne (e),389,276,12,8,19,14,73,35,49,49,139,23,681,405,420,298,260,107
Total,"1,507","1,311",67,63,75,128,283,152,104,206,692,111,"2,728","1,971","1,649","1,502","1,078",469

